# How to Locate the Motherboard Jumper for HP ENVY 17 (s017cl) Laptop?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hp-pavilion, jumper

How can I locate the Motherboard Jumper for HP PAVILION ENVY laptops. Specifically the **s017cl** laptop. I need to perform a CMOS password reset but I can't find the Jumper for the Motherboard located anywhere upon opening the system. I tried looking it up online but I got nothing.

> **EDIT:**
>  I was hoping to reset the BIOS password so I could reinstall windows from a drive. couldn't get the Jumper. I loaded my hard-drive in a another  pc to fix and re-install window,then loaded it in my pc and it recognised the newly installed windows(though I still don't know what my BIOS password is... couldn't care less since everything is back in order).

Comment: If you are trying to reset a bios password, that won't work. Find the cmos battery and disconnect it for a few minutes, then immediately enter the bios and set date and time.

Comment: @Moab I tried the option of removing the CMOS battery and then holding the power button for some time in order to discharge the capacitors but that didn't work. The bios still had the password

Comment: That is because password is not stored in the bios chip. Enter a wrong password 3 times, does it output a code? if so post it.

Comment: @Moab " system disabled `[i 15312926]` " is what it displays

Comment: Try 00070308 as the master password after restarting the laptop.

Comment: @Moab not working

Comment: @Moab If may; How did you come about that being the master password

Comment: https://bios-pw.org/

Comment: is the **Hash Code/Serial example** meant to be appended before the generated password or what does that refer to

Comment: not sure, never saw a code like yours before, probably why it did not work.